# How to insert an unbreakable space when LaTeX3 syntax is turned on

Tags: latex3

Usually `~` is used to insert an unbreakable space, however, it is used to insert a normal space in LaTeX3, if I understand it correctly. So how do I insert an unbreakable space in this case? Just use the penalty to get the same affect?

Comment: Use `\nobreakspace`